# Auto backup a directory to ftp server with separate files

Tags: backup, cronjob

I have 2 Ubuntu servers (Master and Mirror) and want to use cronjob to auto backup from specific directory.

I read [this](http://forums.eukhost.com/f30/automated-remote-backup-using-ftp-commands-cron-job-12316/). It is OK but not matched my task.

Description my task: Work as real mirror, if Master has any things, mirror has same things

```
Working directory
Master Server: /home/important //need backup
Mirror Server: /home/mirror //backup to this
FTP: ftp.mirror-server.com
FTP user:
mirror FTP password: pass
```

Cronjob will work hourly, upload all files (in separate, not tar) from /home/important (on Master Server) to /home/mirror (on Mirror Server) if they are not existed on /home/mirror

This task will save my bandwidth because files are uploaded by member every time (more than 500 GB)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest sitecopy for synchronization via FTP: http://www.manyfish.co.uk/sitecopy/

If it doesn't have to be FTP, there would be more options like rsync.